# Sum convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

I want to check this sum: $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{(3n+1)!}{n!(2n+1)!}*7^{-n})$$

I think, the easiest way is to use the ratio test:

$$\frac{\frac{(3n+4)!7^{-(n+1)}}{(n+1)!(2n+1)!}}{\frac{(3n+1)!}{n!(2n+1)!}7^{-n}} =\frac{(3n+4)!7^{-(n+1)}n!(2n+1)!}{(n+1)!(2n+3)!(3n+1)!7^{-n}}=\frac{(3n+4)!(2n+1)!}{(n+1)7(2n+3)!(3n+1)!}$$

But how should I proceed?
Thank you for your help
queenD

Comment: As an aside, for $|x|<\dfrac4{27}$, we have: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(3n+1)!}{n!~(2n+1)!}x^n ~=~ \frac{2\sin\bigg(\dfrac23\arcsin\dfrac{3\sqrt{3x}}2\bigg)}{\sqrt{3x~(4-27x)}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your work:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(3n+4)!}{7^{n+1}(n+1)!(2n+3)!}\cdot\frac{7^nn!(2n+1)!}{(3n+1)!}=$$

$$=\frac17\frac{(3n+2)(3n+3)(3n+4)}{(n+1)(2n+2)(2n+3)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{27}{28}<1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(3n+4)!(2n+1)!}{(n+1)7(2n+3)!(3n+1)!}
= \frac{(3n+4)(3n+3)(3n+2)}{(n+1)7(2n+3)(2n+2)} \to \frac{27}{28}<1
$$
hence the series converges.

I only used the definition of the factorial.